# Multiple return type from API

Tags: c#, rest

#### Input and API definition :

I'm consuming the following API, that responde either with a `Data` object of an `Error` object

FooBar Method:  Ids is a list of string separated by commas

```
GET: /FooBar/v1{?ids}
GET: /FooBar/v1/{ids}
```

Request Header:

```
X-FooBar-Key:   ## My key ##
```

Response : 200

```
// if there is multiple IDs, response is an array of Data and Error
[{
  "data": { }
}, {
  "data": { }
}, {
  "error": { }
}]

//If there is only one ID, response is the content of the data object
{
    "code":     "",
    "date":     "",
    "status":   "",
    "message":  "",
    "link":     "",
    "type":     ""
}
```

Response : 400/404/etc  , Return the content of an Error object

```
{
    "code":     "",
    "message":  ""
}
```

#### Output and Expected results:

I want to be able to check [1, N] IDs and with only one object return type `Response` with either Data or Error initialised the other at null...

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public Error Error { get; set; }

    public string Id{  get; set; }
} 
public class Error
{
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("code")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public ErrorCode Code { get; set; }
}    
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

#### Attempt:

In order to simply the problem For now I work only on 1 Id at a time.
Using ServiceStack Client to consume the REST API.

```
public class FooBarAPI : IFooBarAPI
{
    Dictionary<string, string> DefaultHeader;
    string BasePath; // https://foofoo.bar/FooBar/v1
    public FooBarAPI(Dictionary<string, string> defaultHeader, string basePath)
    {
        DefaultHeader = defaultHeader;
        BasePath = basePath;
    }

    public Response GetFooBar(string id)
    {
        JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient(BasePath);
        client.RequestFilter = httpReq => httpReq.Headers.Add("X-FooBar-Key", DefaultHeader["X-FooBar-Key"]);

        var response = 
                client.GetAsync<Response>($"/{id}");    // Null as for one ID the result is type Data not Response
                // client.GetAsync<Data>($"/{id}");     // Working If not Error  

        var toto = response.Result;
        toto.Id = id;

        return toto;
    }

    public Response[] GetFooBar(string[] ids)
    {   // 
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This question is not tagged with ServiceStack as I'm open to solution using : 
HttpWebRequest/Response Class, 
WebClient Class, 
HttpClient Class, 
RestSharp NuGet Package, 
ServiceStack Http Utils, Or Anything that make my life easier.

I am using ServiceStack because of [documentation](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#async-example) saying that I could use something like :

```
client.GetAsync(new Hello { Name = "World!" })
    .Success(r => r => r.Result.Print())
    .Error(ex => { throw ex; });
```

Using `Success` and `Error` to map single return type to my `Response` type.

Comment: Is the API code written by you?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, No. But the guy that lead this project wrote a white paper about designing API. I will galdy forward any critism to him.

Comment: There is not strict rule that Error and Response can not be returned differently. Actually when Error is returned, the HttpResponseCode will not be 200. So the client need to check the HttpResponseCode from the response before trying to deserialize the response content.  If the API is part of the same product, team, division, company it can be discussed and implemented to return a wrapper object instead of different objects. But that's entirely up to owners of the code. As an API client, you do not have any way out of it to get the response in the same class until the API changes it's response

Comment: When asking for a List of IDs if one of them is valid the response is 200.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ServiceStack, then you should use it the way you found in the doc, but this would mean that you actually throw (a custom) exception when ever the id does not exist. Your custom exception would then include the code and message. So you would actually just throw an exception when ever you want to return an error.

However, I don't think that is what you should do, because exceptions should only be used if an exceptional case happens, but as far as I understand, errors is a common and normal behavior that happens often (like the client does try and error with ids). Therefore, I recommend using HttpWebResponse Class as your return type. There you can basically set the HTTP return state (e.g. 400, 404) and json (or actually any) data.

Comment: "For you it's an exception for me it's an other Thursday."-M. Bison.  The service will send a 404 not found for anything older than 1 mounth. Not my design. And that for a list of ID {valid, valid, invalid} I will get a 200. And the response array will have multiple type in it

Comment: I would definitely use HttpWebResponse then, it gives you much more flexibility as you can excactely define what response you want to return in each case.

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack [C#/.NET Service Clients](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client) supports both Sync and Async APIs, since your method is synchronous you should only be using the synchronous APIs, e.g:

```
public Response GetFooBar(string id)
{
    var client = new JsonServiceClient(BasePath) { 
        RequestFilter = req => req.Headers.Add(
            "X-FooBar-Key", DefaultHeader["X-FooBar-Key"])
    }

    try 
    {
        var response = client.Get<Response>($"/{id}");
        response.Id = id; // Why isn't this already in the response?
        return response;
    }
    catch (WebServiceException ex)
    {
        //Error Details
        //ex.StatusCode;
        //ex.ErrorCode;
        //ex.ErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

You should **only** use the async APIs if your method is also async, e.g:

```
public async Task<Response> GetFooBar(string id)
{
    var client = new JsonServiceClient(BasePath) { 
        RequestFilter = req => req.Headers.Add(
            "X-FooBar-Key", DefaultHeader["X-FooBar-Key"])
    }

    try 
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync<Response>($"/{id}");
        response.Id = id; // Why isn't this already in the response?
        return response;
    }
    catch (WebServiceException ex)
    {
        //Error Details
        //ex.StatusCode;
        //ex.ErrorCode;
        //ex.ErrorMessage;
    }
}
```